# Is there a way for me to assign one of these values without using the Java 12 new switch implementation?

Tags: java, replace, switch-statement

This is the code, what could I do to replace the switch to something available at language level 11?

```
private final int MAX_AUTORES = switch (this.getClass().getSimpleName()) {
        case "Artigo", "Resumo" -> 8;
        case "Minicurso" -> 3;
        case "Monografia", "Palestra" -> 1;
        case "RelatorioTecnico" -> 4;

        default -> throw new IllegalStateException("Valor inesperado: " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
};
```

Comment: you could use a `Map` to decode, like e.g. shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59123345/1428369), put it in a function

Comment: **Don't!** A super class should not know its subclasses like that. For one, because it is very error-prone. Make the constructor take `maxAutores` as an argument, and have the subclasses specify the value they need. That way, if a subclass is renamed, no change needed here, and if a new subclass is added, the compiler will force you to assign a value, rather than wait for it to fail at run-time. Alternatively, create an *abstract* `getMaxAutores()` method that the subclasses must implement. That way you're not wasting space on replacting the same value for every instance of the same subclass.

Comment: ahhh, of course...